# Chern-Simons, General relativity, and notations

Tags: electromagnetism, general-relativity, lagrangian-formalism, differential-geometry, notation

Consider the Einstein-Maxwell-dilaton theory with an additional Chern-Simons term as in this [paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1303.7211)

\begin{equation}
S = \int d^4 \sqrt{-g} \left[ \frac{1}{2} R - \frac{1}{2} (\partial\varphi)^2 - \frac{\tau(\varphi)}{4} F^2 - V(\varphi) \right] -\frac{1}{2} \int \theta(\varphi)  F\wedge F.
\end{equation}
with $F=d A$ being the field strength. Take for example the gauge equations:

\begin{equation}
d(\tau\star F + \theta F) =0.
\end{equation}

I have two questions coming from my ignorance on the topic:

1. What does the operation $\wedge$ mean and what is the explicit expression for $F \wedge F$?
2. What does the operation $\star$ mean and what is the explicit expression for $\tau\star F$?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exterior_algebra

Comment: The $d$ in $dA$ and in your gauge equation is called an [exterior derivative](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exterior_derivative).

Answer (score 4):

The $\wedge$ in $F\wedge F$ is the [wedge product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differential_form) of two copies of the curvature  2-form
$$
F= \frac 12 F_{\mu\nu} dx^\mu \wedge dx^\nu=dA.
$$
where
$$
A= A_\mu dx^\mu 
$$
and
$$
dA= d(A_\nu dx^\nu ) = (\partial_\mu A_\nu) dx^\mu\wedge dx^\nu= \frac 12 (\partial_\mu A_\nu-\partial_\nu A_\mu) dx^\mu\wedge dx^\nu.
$$
Thus
$$
F\wedge F= \frac 14 F_{\mu\nu}F_{\rho\sigma}dx^\mu \wedge dx^\nu \wedge dx^\rho\wedge  dx^\sigma = \frac 14 \epsilon^{\mu\nu\rho\sigma} F_{\mu\nu}F_{\rho\sigma}d^4x 
$$

The $\star$ is the [Hodge star dual](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hodge_star_operator)
and $\tau$ is just multiplication by the function $\tau(\phi)$.

If you plan to work in an  area using these things, you need to learn the calculus of differential forms. Indeed, even if you do not plan such work, you should learn this calculus as it opens many doors.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Just for the record, I am finding really useful section 2.9 of Carroll's book: https://www.preposterousuniverse.com/spacetimeandgeometry/